# What is the proper way to issue a redirect from a ReactJS / Reflux component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, refluxjs

I have an Actions class created via `Reflux.createActions()`, a Store class which extends `Reflux.Store` (ES6-style), and a Component which extends `Reflux.Component`.

The component is effectively just a simple `<Button />` which the user can click on. When clicked, it makes a PUT request to the server. Most of the time, the response causes a state change to the Store. However, for certain responses, I need it to redirect to another page in my web application completely.

I'm very new to React so forgive my ignorance here. I assumed it would be something like this:

```
class MyStore extends Reflux.Store {

    // ...more code here...

    onActionCompleted(response) {
        if (response.specialCase === true) {
            this.props.history.push('/special');
        } else {
            // ...update state...
        }
    }

}
```

However that doesn't seem to do it. What is the proper way to go about doing arbitrary, programmatic redirects in React?

Comment: what version of react-router are you using?

Comment: is onActionCompleted a component instance method, or an instance method of MyStore?

Comment: It's an instance method of MyStore. And I believe we're on React-Router 4.2.0.